# How to cast T[] to IEnumerable<T> at runtime

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a Generic Function that needs to interpret a dynamic variable at runtime:

```cs
U[] HandleDynamic<U>(dynamic value)
    if (value is IEnumerable enumerable)
    {
        // get all typeof(T) for each implemented IEnumerable<T>
        Type[] types = enumerable
                        .GetType()
                        .GetInterfaces() // all implemented interfaces
                        .Where(x => x.IsGenericType && (x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>))) // all IEnumerable<> interfaces
                        .Select(x => x.GetGenericArguments().First()) //  gets first of all generic arguments in each IEnumerable<> since IEnumerable<> only has one generic Type Argument
                        .ToArray();
        // get all constructors that accept a type in types
        foreach (Type type in types)
        {
            ConstructorInfo? ctor = typeof(U)
                            .GetConstructor(
                                BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance, 
                                new Type[]
                                {
                                    type        // the first Generic type Argument of IEnumerable<> (-> T)
                                });

            if (ctor is not null)
            {
                return value.Select(new Func<dynamic, U>(o => (U)ctor.Invoke(new object[] { o }))).ToArray(); // Syntax Error here
            }
        }
    }
    throw new InvalidCastException();
}
```

If I have a custom class like so:

```cs
internal class LongProxy
{
    long _value;
    public LongProxy(long value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }
}
```

When I then call my code like so:

```cs
dynamic[] myDynamicArray = new long[10];
LongProxy[] myProxyArray = HandleDynamic<LongProxy>(myDynamicArray);
```

I get the Syntax error `System.Array does not contain a definition for 'Select'` at `return ...` in HandleDynamic. That kind of makes sense since `value` is still a `dynamic{long[]}`. How would I convert the array into an IEnumerable? I could use reflection (again), but I was hoping that something similar to `(IEnumerable<dynamic>)value` works as a cast. The correct cast would be `IEnumerable<type>`, but that doesn't work since `type` is a variable, not a Type.

Comment: You don't need to use `dynamic` here. In fact, just avoid it completely.

Comment: `IEnumerable` does not imply `IEnumerable<T>`: any `class` can implement `IEnumerable` alone, in which case your method will break. And there are a lot of `IEnumerable`-only types in .NET, such as `NameValueCollection`.

Comment: Every time you use `dynamic`, a kitten dies. Please don't harm any more kittens.

Comment: `internal class LongProxy { ... }`  <-- This is not a proxy object.

Comment: You can't call extension methods on `dynamic` objects since the runtime doesn't know what they are. You need to manually call the method, for example `var result = System.Linq.Enumerable.Select(value, new Func...);`

Comment: @Dai It is a simplified example, I read my Types from a file at Runtime, so dynamic seems like the best option. I know `IEnumerable` does not imply `IEnumerable<T>`, hence I was asking for something similar to `IEnumerable<dynamic>`. Why is LongProxy not a Proxy?
@DavidG Sorry for killing kittens :(
Thanks for the tip on manually calling the extension Method!

Comment: `LongProxy` is not a proxy because it doesn't forward anything. `Int64` (`long`) is a value-type: it's passed-by-value: updating `myProxyArray[123] = new LongProxy( 456 );` will not effect any change in `myDynamicArray`.

Comment: ...also, what is the purpose of all this? What **real** problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: You are not really using dynamic here anyway, you do the whole thing via reflection. Replace `dynamic` with `IEnumerable` in declaration and then instead of using `Select` just use foreach loop over it (that's the only place you use `value`). Or you can replace `dynamic` with `object` though I don't see a reason since you throw exception anyway if its not `IEnumerable`. If you don't like foreach loops for some reason - use `value.Cast<object>.Select(...)`

Comment: Your title question is opposite what your code implies. Why are you using reflection anyway? If you already know it's enumerable, just iterate the collection and populate into an array (list -> ToArray).